# Error: "'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position" in Python 3

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, python-3.3

I wrote a program that recursively searches for files with a particular extension in folders and does some processing. Strangely, the program runs fine with somewhere around 85 files and then crashes on the same file every time. I don't think there's anything different about that file or filename. Because it runs fine for 85 files, I know the error is not about my code per se, but more about the wrong compiler maybe?

OS: `Linux arctic 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Error details (complete Traceback):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scoretotal.py", line 98, in <module>
    main()   
  File "scoretotal.py", line 96, in main
    find_score_files()
  File "scoretotal.py", line 89, in find_score_files
    total = calculate_total((os.path.join(root,filename)))
  File "scoretotal.py", line 14, in calculate_total
    lines = file_object_read.read()
  File    "/soft/linux/bin/../python3.3.3/lib/python3.3/encodings/ascii.py", line 26, in decode
    return codecs.ascii_decode(input, self.errors)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 17: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm running `Python 3.3.3`. From my research online, it may have something to do with unicode or UTF-8 format, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. What is going wrong?

Comment: Which OS? It makes a big difference.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Linux, by the looks of the traceback..

Comment: You gave us an incomplete traceback. Can you give us the *whole* traceback please? The code that triggers this would be helpful too.

Comment: And most likely there is something odd about that particular filename, actually.

Comment: I updated my question to include the complete Traceback and details of the OS.

Answer (score 5):

When you open a file without specifying an encoding, Python will pick one for you; in your case it picked `ascii`, which is reasonably safe in that it's unlikely to give you back the wrong characters, but runs into errors quite easily. You need to check with the source of those files to find out their encoding and include it in the `open` call. For example if you've determined that the files were written with ISO-8859-1 encoding:

```
file_object_read = open(path, 'r', encoding='iso-8859-1')
```

If you *don't* know what encoding to use you'll have to guess, and accept that sometimes your guess will be wrong. On Linux you could try `'utf-8'` and on Windows you could try `'mbcs'`, as those are the defaults used by other programs on those systems. There are utilities available that will inspect the file contents and try to make an educated guess, including the [`chardet` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).

Comment: Anecdotally, I would say "windows-1252" is the most popular file character set on Windows.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack "mbcs" isn't an actual encoding, it just tells Python to use whatever your version of Windows is configured for. Most of the time it will be identical to "windows-1252".

Comment: That's awesome to know! Thank you for the correction :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with the difference between ' and ‘ or " and “... These (what I call) pretty quotes tend to ruin pythons day.

It may not be this exactly but it is certainly something to do with the character set in the file. As seen here: http://effbot.org/pyfaq/what-does-unicodeerror-ascii-decoding-encoding-error-ordinal-not-in-range-128-mean.htm

I would recommend a try catch, excepting errors and casting to ascii.

Comment: I am not familiar with those quotes. So from what I understand, you suspect that this particular file contains these "pretty quotes" and Python can't decode them?